# File Copying using byte buffer slightly increasing file size of destination file, in Java

Tags: java, file

I am creating a simple file copying application for my personal use. But when i run the program, the output file is slightly larger than the source file. I am using buffers depending on the file size, which are as follows

1. if file size less than 9 KB than buffer is 512 Bytes.
2. if file size less than 9 MB than buffer size is 512*1024 Bytes (512 KB).
3. if file size less than 99 MB than buffer is 1024*1024 Bytes (1 MB).
4. other wise buffer size is 2*1024*1024 Bytes (approx 2.5 MB).

Source Code

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    /**
    * mcopy
    */
public class mcopy {

private static byte buffersm[] = new byte[512]; // buffer for upto 9kb
private static byte buffermd[] = new byte[512 * 1024]; // buffer for upto 9 MB
private static byte bufferlg[] = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // buffer for upto 99MB
private static byte bufferxl[] = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024]; // buffer for above 100MB
private static FileInputStream fin = null;
private static FileOutputStream fout = null;
private static int i = 0;
private static double length = 0;
private static double j = 0;
private static DecimalFormat decimal_p_ = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

private static void copysm(File a, File b) {
    try {
        length = a.length();
        fin = new FileInputStream(a);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(b);
        i = fin.read(buffersm);
        j = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            j += i;
            fout.write(buffersm);
            System.out.print("Copying... " + decimal_p_.format(((j / length) * 100)) + " " + a.getName() + " to "
                    + b.getPath() + " buffer: " + buffersm.length + " \r");
            i = fin.read(buffersm);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void copymd(File a, File b) {
    try {
        length = a.length();
        fin = new FileInputStream(a);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(b);
        i = fin.read(buffermd);
        j = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            j += i;
            fout.write(buffermd);
            System.out.print("Copying... " + decimal_p_.format(((j / length) * 100)) + " " + a.getName() + " to "
                    + b.getPath() + " buffer: " + buffermd.length + " \r");
            i = fin.read(buffermd);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void copylg(File a, File b) {
    try {
        length = a.length();
        fin = new FileInputStream(a);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(b);
        i = fin.read(bufferlg);
        j = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            j += i;
            fout.write(bufferlg);
            System.out.print("Copying... " + decimal_p_.format(((j / length) * 100)) + " " + a.getName() + " to "
                    + b.getPath() + " buffer: " + bufferlg.length  + " \r");
            i = fin.read(bufferlg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void copyxl(File a, File b) {
    try {
        length = a.length();
        fin = new FileInputStream(a);
        fout = new FileOutputStream(b);
        i = fin.read(bufferxl);
        j = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            j += i;
            fout.write(bufferxl);
            System.out.print("Copying... " + decimal_p_.format(((j / length) * 100)) + " " + a.getName() + " to "
                    + b.getPath() + " buffer: " + bufferxl.length  + " \r");
            i = fin.read(bufferxl);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fin.close();
            fout.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File in = new File(args[0]);
    File out = new File(args[1]);
    double ld = in.length();
    double l = ld / 1024 / 1024;
    if (l <= ((9 * 1024) / 1024 / 1024)) {
        copysm(in, out);
    } else if (l <= 9) {
        copymd(in, out);
    } else if (l <= 99) {
        copylg(in, out);
    } else {
        copyxl(in, out);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

File Size comparison....: 
The Source File: "Dragon Ball Episode 84.mp4"..... file size: 8,59,93,580 bytes 
The Destination File: "sample.mp4"..... file szie: 8,70,31,808 bytes

[Command used to run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOsWJ.png)

[Comparison between the files used and named in this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYEWC.png)

Comment: Be careful of your nomenclature, 1 MB = 1,000,000 bytes.  What you are talking about here is MiB = 1024 x 1024 bytes.  The file size difference is caused because your entire buffer is always being written, even though most of it is unused for the last chunk.  (87,031,808 = 83 x 1024 x 1024).

Comment: 1 Bytes and 1024 times is 1 KB

Comment: 1024 KB is 1 MB therefor 1MB = 1024*1024

Comment: No sir.  1 KB = 1000 bytes.  1 KiB is 1024 bytes.  (Similarly, 1 MB = 1000 x 1000 and 1 MiB = 1024 x 1024)  Please see this: [Binary Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

Comment: sorry for my reply for file size.... but is their any remedy for it....

Comment: i want remove this problem as it wil hurt size of files which are going to be VERY large.... in case

Comment: Then stop using `FileOutputStream.write(byte[])` and use `FileOutputStream.write(byte[], offset, len)` and only write the used data rather than the entire buffer

Comment: thanks for that Tibrogargan... waiting for more methods to resolve. I think this is the answer I wanted although.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much going to do what you're doing now, but only copy what was read, instead of the entire contents of the buffer.  Essentially the main difference is to use `FileOutputStream.write(byte[], offset, len)` instead of  `FileOutputStream.write(byte[])`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
* mcopy
*/
public class mcopy {
    private static DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    private final static int SMALL = 512;
    private final static int MEDIUM = 512 * 1024;
    private final static int LARGE = 1024 * 1024;
    private final static int XLARGE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;


    private static void copy(File a, File b, byte[] buffer) {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        try {
            double j = 0;
            double length = a.length();
            fin = new FileInputStream(a);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(b);

            int i;
            while(-1 != (i = fin.read(buffer))) {
                j += i;
                fout.write(buffer, 0, i);
                System.out.print("Copying... " + format.format(((j / length) * 100)) + " " + a.getName() + " to "
                    + b.getPath() + " buffer: " + buffer.length + " \r");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File in = new File(args[0]);
        File out = new File(args[1]);
        double ld = in.length();
        double l = ld / 1024 / 1024;

        byte[] buffer = null;

        if (l <= ((9 * 1024) / 1024 / 1024)) {
            buffer = new byte[SMALL];
        } else if (l <= 9) {
            buffer = new byte[MEDIUM];
        } else if (l <= 99) {
            buffer = new byte[LARGE];
        } else {
            buffer = new byte[XLARGE];
        }
        copy(in, out, buffer);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for shortning my code...... i just created separate method for each size of buffer.... because when the file size is very low, i.e., uptill 20mb, showing progress is not required as copy process is done in micro seconds...... thanks for reply and answer.... marking my question as answered for yours